# Getting Error on Two Events happening on same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I'm having the activiti Bpmn file, in that there is having transition of task. While transition I need to create the due date for that new task. my problem is due date and new task happening on same time. because of that I'm getting error.

```
                    onClose: function (date) {
                        if (valid) {
                            date = Date.parse(date);
                            if (oldDate !== date) {
                                var tasks = getSet(context, 'task') || getSet(context, 'tasks'),
                                trans = Ember.get(context, 'transition') || Ember.get(context, 'propertyMap.transition'),
                                requestData = [];
                            if (!tasks.length) {
                                resolve();
                                return;
                            }
                            if (!trans) {
                                trans = 'Done';
                            }
                                tasks.forEach(function (task) {
                                 requestData.push({ name: 'id', value: (Ember.get(task, 'id') || Ember.get(task, 'currentTask.id') )});
                                requestData.push({ name: 'transition', value: trans || '' });
                            });
                            if (context.get('serviceParams')) {
                                Object.asAjaxData(context.get('serviceParams')).forEach(function (param) {
                                   requestData.push(param);
                                });
                            }

                         return (Core.services({
                            type: 'post',
                            service: 'workflow/task/transition',
                            data: requestData,
                            json: true
                        })
                        .done(function (res) {
                                Core.Action('Core:updateTask', context, { dtDue: date });
                            Core.model.ingestResources(res);
                            var inspected = Core.controller.detailsObject,
                                wf = res.workflows || {};
                            if (inspected) {
                                Object.keys(wf).forEach(function (w) {
                                    var hist = wf[w].historicalTaskIds;
                                    if (hist.contains(inspected.currentTaskId)) {
                                        inspected.set('currentTaskId', wf[w].openTaskIds[0]);
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            resolve();
                        })
                        .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
                            Core.Error.show(error);
                        })
                        .always(function () {
                            tasks.forEach(function (task) {
                                if (Ember.get(task, 'isClip')) {
                                    Core.model.clip.clear();
                                }
                            });
                            var wfController = Core.Tab.Workflow.getController();
                            var sel = wfController.get('selection');
                            wfController.reloadResultSet();
                            var rs = wfController.get('resultSet');
                            rs && rs.done(function () {
                                var s = Ember.Set.create();
                                rs.get('content').forEach(function (item) {
                                    if (!item) { return; }
                                    s.addObject(item);
                                });
                                sel.forEach(function (item) {
                                   if (!s.contains(item)) {
                                       sel.remove(item);
                                   }
                                });
                            });
                            sel.clear();
                            resolve(tasks);
                        })
                    );




                            }
                        }
                    }
```

In that `Core.Action('Core:updateTask', context, { dtDue: date });` is using for updating the duedate. If I use on the top `If` statement Due Date is updated, but Transistion is not happening. If I'm using on the `done` function, the transistion is happened and moved to the new Task Id. Because of that it searching Task Id and showing error.
Please provide me suggestion on this. I need to create both the Transistion and meanwhile update the date.

Comment: which library are you using for Core....?

Comment: @ducmai Ember 1.4.0

Comment: can you share the server logs?